# Disable VPN on Cisco PIX 506e (v6.3) and configure VPN pass through to a Windows 2003 DC/RRAS

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-pix

The company I work for has a client that has a Cisco PIX 506e firewall running v6.3.  The PIX is currently set up to manage PPTP VPN connections using the local Windows domain controller as a RADIUS server.  The PIX does not support MSCHAP v2 connections, so users cannot connect from Windows 7 workstations.

Our plan is to just disable the VPN connection on the PIX and pass VPN through and let the DC manage it.  Problem is, I cannot find any information on disabling the existing VPN setup on the PIX.

I have only moderate experience with PIX's, but to the best of my knowledge, the following is all the commands that control the VPN setup.

```
vpdn group 1 accept dialin pptp
vpdn group 1 ppp authentication pap
vpdn group 1 ppp authentication chap
vpdn group 1 ppp authentication mschap
vpdn group 1 ppp encryption mppe 40
vpdn group 1 client configuration address local bigpool
vpdn group 1 client configuration dns local_server_alias 
vpdn group 1 client configuration wins local_server_alias
vpdn group 1 client authentication aaa RADIUS
vpdn group 1 pptp echo 60
vpdn username some_users password ********
vpdn enable outside
```

I've looked at the PIX v6.3 [command reference](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/pix/pix63/command/reference/tz.html) and I do not seen any information on disabling it.  The `tftp-server` commands reference using a `no` command to disable the tftp-server, but the vpnd command reference has no information on it.  To disable, is it as simple as using a `no vpdn enable outside` command or doing a `no` for all of the above commands, or is it something else?

Second, related question is then how to correctly pass VPN through the pix.

Reviewed [Cisco Doc ID 18806](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_configuration_example09186a0080094a5a.shtml#pptpwith) and it looks like all I need to do is add the following lines:

```
access-list acl-out permit gre any host external_ip_of_RRAS 
access-list acl-out permit tcp any host external_ip_of_RRAS eq 1723 
static (inside,outside) external_ip_of_RRAS internal_ip_of_RRAS netmask 255.255.255.255 0 0 
access-group acl-out in interface outside
```

There is also potentially a PPTP `fixup` command that may be needed, but it sounds like that is only needed for inside to outside PPTP.  Does this look correct or will I need anything more?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find yourself in a world of pain if you apply 'acl-out' to your outside interface! If there is already an access-group applied then there is a risk that you will remove all of your existing inbound access.

Before you do anything do a show access-group to check what acl's are already applied (if any). I don't have a PIX v6 to check exactly what the commands would but it'll be something like:-

```
pix501# show access-group
```

and you should get a response something like...

```
access-group outside_acl in interface outside
access-group inside_acl in interface inside
```

If you do have an access-list applied to your outside interface then you'll want to add to that one rather than creating a new one

```
pix501(config)# access-list outside_acl permit gre any host external_ip_of_RRAS 
pix501(config)# access-list outside_acl permit tcp any host external_ip_of_RRAS eq 1723
pix501(config)# static (inside,outside) external_ip_of_RRAS internal_ip_of_RRAS
```

If you don't have an access-list applied to your outside interface, then go ahead an apply that to your outside interface as you have said above.

```
pix501(config)# access-group outside_acl in interface outside
```

To disable the exisiting pptp all you need to do is 'no' the vpnd enable statement

```
pix501(config)# no vpdn enable outside
```

Similarly, if you want to completely remove all of the vpdn config, just type 'no' in front of the configuration line you'd like to remove

```
pix501(config)# no vpdn group 1 accept dialin pptp
pix501(config)# no vpdn group 1 ppp authentication pap
pix501(config)# no vpdn group 1 ppp authentication chap
pix501(config)# no vpdn group 1 ppp authentication mschap
pix501(config)# no vpdn group 1 ppp encryption mppe 40
pix501(config)# no vpdn group 1 client configuration address local bigpool
pix501(config)# no vpdn group 1 client configuration dns local_server_alias 
pix501(config)# no vpdn group 1 client configuration wins local_server_alias
pix501(config)# no vpdn group 1 client authentication aaa RADIUS
pix501(config)# no vpdn group 1 pptp echo 60
pix501(config)# no vpdn username some_users
```

Comment: There actually is an access list already created for the outside interface. `access-group outside_access_in in interface outside`  I had intended to update that from the Cisco example, but was so caught up in removing identifiable IPs & names from our internal config that I forgot.  Thanks a lot.  Will not be able to test & confirm this until later.